# How to use bootstrap dismissible alerts in html/php/JQuery and change $_SESSION array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have notifications on an $_SESSION array:
f ex.
    11=>'1234-Client A:Message is coming, Ok:0'
    14=>'3456-Client B:Message is coming, Not Ok:3'
aso.

I loop through these to print it out in dismissible bootstrap alerts.
The last indicator in the message is deciding what alert to use.

When I close a notification I want to close it AND update the $_SESSION array with '...:9' to indicate that this is closed and will not show the next time the page is reloaded.
I pass the Id to the JQuery, since this can differ from record to record, but how can I use this on the same PHP-page to change the $_SESSION array for the correct record Id?

I am trying with this code:

invoices.php:

```
...
$id = $_POST["id"];
echo 'Id: ' . $id . '<br />';
...
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['UploadMessage'])) :
    foreach($_SESSION['UploadMessage'] as $key => $val):
        $pos    = strrpos($val, ":");
        $alert  = substr($val, $pos+1);
        $val = substr($val, 0, $pos);
        echo $val . ' ' . $alert . '<br />'; //'\n'
        $message = $val; ?>

        <?php if($alert == 0) : ?>
            <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" id="<?=$key;?>" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true" id="<?=$key;?>">&times;</span></button>
                <strong>Ok! </strong><?=$message?>
                <a href="#" class="alert-link pull-right" style="float:right,font-size=21px,font-weight:bold,line-height:1,opacity:2">X</a>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if($alert == 1) : ?>
            <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible" id="<?=$key;?>" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true" id="<?=$key;?>">&times;</span></button>
                <strong>Info! </strong><?=$message?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if($alert == 2) : ?>
            <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" id="<?=$key;?>" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true" id="<?=$key;?>">&times;</span></button>
                <strong>Warning! </strong><?=$message?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if($alert == 3) : ?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" id="<?=$key;?>" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true" id="<?=$key;?>">&times;</span></button>
                <strong>Åtgärda! </strong><?=$message?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

...

<!-- JavaScript -->
<script>
$('button.close').on('click', function (obj) {
    var id = obj.target.id;
    console.log("Close "+id);
    $.post('invoices.php', { 'id': 'id'});
});
</script>
```

I know that PHP has already loaded the document when the foreach-loop
is running, but how can I pass the value of the array-Id when I click the
close button on each notification and change the array value for this?

Can anyone help a newbie out?

I have tried changing the javascript into this, but it doesn't work.
I get the correct id in the alert box, but no update of $_SESSION is made when I reload the page.

```
    //    $.post('invoices_ajax.php', { 'id': 'id'});
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'invoices_ajax.php',
      data: ({id:id}),
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
      }
    });
});
```

In my Ajax file I have this code:

```
<?php

    $id=$_POST['id'];
    echo $id;

    if(isset($_SESSION['UploadMessage'])) {
        foreach($_SESSION['UploadMessage'] as $k => &$v) {
            echo $k . ' ' . $v . '<br />';
            if($k == $id) {
                $pos    = strrpos($v, ":");
                $v      = substr($v, 0, $pos).':9';
                echo $v . '<br />';
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Will need to send ajax request to have php modify session

Comment: If I post to a dummy php the id-variable, echo this out, will I return to this document and have the id-variable set?

Comment: And where exactly are you starting your session? Unless your server is configured to do that automatically, you need to explicitly do it. And _updating_ the session would require some sort of write operation, `$_SESSION[…] = …` -don’t see that anywhere either.